# Is there any way I can read all .csv's in a directory into r if some may have different number of columns?

Tags: r

I am currently using the following to import the csv's:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
         read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I have been using the following to create a common list of variables that I would like all of the data frames to format to:

```
vars_common <- names(LogBaseline1)
```

Then I am using an `rbind.fill` command to append the rest of the data in the same format as this baseline:

```
DataSet1 <- DataSet1[vars_common]
```

etc.. with all datasets.

Is there any way I can do all of this during the import step or is there a way to call all data that was imported and limit all the data frames to only these variables to create a data frame of all with only the columns I want?

Comment: What exactly are you calling the "import step"? I mean, you are going to have to read in the data if you want to know what columns it contains. I'm not sure which part you are looking to do better. Seems like you are doing the right thing already.

Comment: Use `lapply` to read the files and do the editing within an anonymous function: `df = lapply(temp, function(x) { dat = read.csv(x); ...code to change column names...})`. Now you have a list containing all your data frames. Then, to combine into a single data frame, `df = do.call(rbind, df)`.

Comment: Get rid of the `list2env`, as soon as you get rid of the list structure everything is harder. If you have a list of data frames and you know the common column names then you can `do.call(rbind, lapply(list_of_data, function(x) x[vars_common]))`

Comment: `fread` from the `data.table` package allows you to specify the columns you wish to read by name ahead of reading. Also `rbind.data.table` automatically fills columns that do not exist in all datasets with `NA`.